# Remapping :help in Vim to open in a new tab

Tags: vim

The default behaviour of `:help` in Vim opens the help in a horizontal split.

I need to remap `:help` to instead execute `:tab help` as to always open the help in a new tab.

How can I remap this command?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878692/aliasing-a-command-in-vim

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
:cabbrev help tab help
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7515418/79125) on how to prevent the above abbreviation from converting `:e help.txt` to `:e tab help.txt` (which would give you an error).

Comment: Thanks @pydave, here is the command for lazy copy pasters like me: `cnoreabbrev <expr> h getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'h' ? 'tab help' : 'h'`