# Vim alias for changing directory

Tags: vim, alias

I’m looking for a way to add a custom command or alias to my vimrc to quickly change to different directories within Vim.  I had something set up once, but lost that config.  This is for a Linux setup.

Basically, I want to set an alias (all-lowercase, if possible; Vim seems to want custom commands to start with an uppercase letter) such as:

```
:cdscripts
```

and have the result be the same as typing:

```
:cd /home/username/.../Scripts
```

I have used NERDTree, but am looking for something a little bit faster.  I have also tried these:

[Aliasing a command in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878692/aliasing-a-command-in-vim)

[CommandAlias : Make aliases to vim command](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4250)

but can’t quite get the results I’m looking for. Is this possible?

Comment: why not just use mapping? `nnoremap somekey :cd /..../<cr>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom command is very easy:

```
:command Cdscripts cd /home/username/.../Scripts
```

To avoid clashes with built-in commands, these must start with an uppercase letter. You can use the plugin linked in your question or [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) to create a lowercase alias:

```
:Alias cdscripts Cdscripts
```

Comment: Awesome.  That is pretty simple, somehow I just didn't make it work right ;). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an alias manager doing these thing easily. - [aliasme](https://github.com/Jintin/aliasme)

you can add, remove or jump to declare path you want.

Three step to install

1. mkdir ~/.aliasme
2. curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jintin/aliasme/master/aliasme.sh > ~/.aliasme/aliasme.sh
3. echo "source ~/.aliasme/aliasme.sh" >> [~/.bash_profile (or any login script: bash_rc)]

After install, you can use all these function

1. al add [name] [value]        # add alias with name and value
2. al rm [name]                 # remove alias by name
3. al ls                        # alias list
4. al [name]                    # execute alias associate with [name]

See https://github.com/Jintin/aliasme for more information