# Use capital Q also to quit Vim

Tags: vim

Tried using the following in my `.vimrc`, but somehow it isn't working. Also, is there any down sides to using "Q" also along side the usual q to quit the editor. Apparently, I find stumbling on this issue a lot, but don't see this tweak is most .vimrcs.

```
noremap Q :quit<CR>
```

Comment: Mapping seems to be fine. Are you getting any error?

Comment: May I introduce you to `ZZ` and `ZQ`, `:h ZZ` and `:h ZQ`

Comment: You're defining normal + visual + op-pending mappings. In neither does `q` quit Vim (rather, it starts / stops macro recording). Why you mean is `:q`, which is command-line mode.

Comment: Thanks, for ZZ and ZQ. But somehow I :{q/Q} better as its more difficult to do and might help avoid typos. Also, I prefer not to change case for the command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to quit Vim with `:Q`, a simple mapping won't do, because you then won't be able to type `Q` in the command-line (which is the mode you would have to map, using `:cnoremap`).

You can either just define an uppercase command:

```
:command! -bar -bang Q quit<bang>
```

or use the technique described in [aliasing a command in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878692/aliasing-a-command-in-vim), which also works for lower-case. Or have a look at [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746).

Comment: Wow, it worked well! Quite a newbie to Vim, so still not clear with most of it. But have to admit, I am in love :)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to quit vim with :Q just add this to your vimrc

```
:command Q q
```