# Vim: Overwrite save function for hosts file to be sudo

Tags: vim, hosts-file

I have this in my .vimrc, which is a key mapping to open my hosts file in a new tab:

```
nnoremap <Leader>hs :tabe /etc/hosts<cr>:set noreadonly<cr>
```

So now Vim won't bother me about readonly, which is great. However, when I save, I might compulsively hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> or `:w`. I would like to overwrite both (are they the same?) calls to call our normal NVW (nasty Vim way) to write as sudo:

```
:w !sudo tee % >/dev/null<cr>
```

But I would only like to **do this for this current buffer**, as in the hosts file. Some `setlocal` magic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming macvim since you are using command. I don't believe `<D-S>` does the same thing as `:w` but I don't know this for sure. You might be able to map to use a buffer local mapping if you wanted.

```
autocmd BufRead /etc/hosts nnoremap <buffer> <D-s> :w !sudo tee % >/dev/null<cr>
```

But you would first need to unmap it from the menu. Using something along the lines of this in your gvimrc.

```
macmenu File.Save key=<nop>
```

And add back the default behavior of save. The buffer local mapping will take precedence.

```
nnoremap <D-s> :w<CR>
```

---

You can override `:w` by using the technique found in [Zyx's Answer on Aliasing a command in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879737/1890567). Which will replace `:w` with `:w !sudo tee % >/dev/null` if it is the only thing on line.

```
autocmd BufRead /etc/hosts cnoreabbrev <buffer> <expr> w ((getcmdtype() is# ':' && getcmdline() is# 'w')?('w !sudo tee % >/dev/null'):('w'))
```