# Vim map :q to quit without saving

Tags: vim

I would like Vim to quit without saving when I enter `:q`.

It annoys me when Vim prompts me to save when I try to quit a document with `:q` having made changes to it. Whenever I want to keep changes I save them. Plus the ! of `:q!` is awkwardly positioned on my UK keyboard. How can I remap `:q` to act like `:q!`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aliasing a command in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878692/aliasing-a-command-in-vim)

Comment: I can see this going very wrong eventually.

Comment: It's worked out OK for me, actually. I guess it comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cabbrev`, that works like a map from a command line instruction to another one, like:

```
:cabbrev q q!
```

So now just type:

```
:q
```

and it will omit changes to exit without asking.